# PHP - Remove BR tags inside UL/OL html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove all html BR tags which are inside UL/OL html tags. For example:

```
Test<br>
<ul>
<li>
Test<br> <!-- THIS <BR> SHOULD BE DELETED BECAUSE IS INSIDE <UL> TAG
</li>
</ul>
```

I created this preg_replace regex:

```
$param_array['description'] = preg_replace('/(?<=<ul>|<\/li>)([\s*<br>\s*|\s*<br\/>\s*|\s*<br \/>\s*]+)(?=<\/ul>|<li>)/is', "$1$3", $param_array['description']);
$param_array['description'] = preg_replace('/(?<=<ol>|<\/li>)([\s*<br>\s*|\s*<br\/>\s*|\s*<br \/>\s*]+)(?=<\/ol>|<li>)/is', "$1$3", $param_array['description']);
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You should use `DOMDocument` instead of `Regex`

Comment: DOMDocudemt will remove all HTML tags inside UL html structure (nodeValue). I want remove only BR tags, everything other tags like <strong>, <span> etc. i wouldn't like to remove.